# Display text after submit button is clicked. PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to catch some text from the textbox, to save it in a variable and then post it on my browser if I click the submit button. My code is this:

```
<?php
$var1=$_POST['text1'];
$var2=$_POST['display'];
    if(isset($var2)){
    var_dump( $var1);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="gdf" name="text1" id="text1" /><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" id="display" name="display"><br /><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is wrong. [The code on rextester](http://rextester.com/HITDG65118)

Comment: Where is your Form? How is this Posting?

Comment: the code on rextester has a form. why does it not work?

Comment: You got 3 answers that are all correct, take a look.

Comment: I know but what is wrong on my rextester?

Comment: Your `FORM` tag has no options set for `POST`, just like all the 3 answers state below. Since no `ACTION` or `METHOD` are set for `FORM`, the browser doesn't know what verb to use nor does it know where to send the data. This is why is is not working.

Comment: Additionally, your Submit button, I would add a `VALUE` to it. This way when the form is posted, you have a value in the index for 'bearbeiten', and then you can more easily confirm the form was submitted: `if(isset($_POST['bearbeiten']))` or `if(!empty($_POST['bearbeiten']))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you need to implement a form on you HTML page and set the action to a new .php page.

```
<form action='display.php' method='post'> 
   *your input fields go here*
```

Now create a new php page (in this case display.php)

Declare the variables as you did....

```
$var1=$_POST['text1'];
$var2=$_POST['display'];
if(isset($var2)){
var_dump( $var1);
```

then you can simply echo each variable accordingly...

**Final Result**
HTML PAGE:

```
<form action='result.php' method='post'> 
  <input type="text" value="gdf" name="text1" id="text1" /><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" id="display" name="display"><br /><br />
</form>
```

**result.php**

```
<?php 
      $var1 = $_POST['text1']; // create variables of your form elements
      $var2 = $_POST['display']; 

      echo '$var1 . ' ' . $display . '.'; 

?>
```

Basically the php page is saying get text1 and display from the form (names) and create variables of them...

Then echo (print) these variables on the screen. (in plain english xD)

p.s 
Your rextester isn't working because you haven't specified a form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms), otherwise you aren't posting anything.
Something like:

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form method="post" action="yourphpfile.php">
        <input type="text" value="gdf" name="text1" id="text1" /><br /><br />
        <input type="text" value="display" name="display" id="display" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit"><br /><br />
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**yourphpfile.php**

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['text1']) and !empty($_POST['display'])){
   $var1=$_POST['text1'];
   $var2=$_POST['display'];
   echo "$var1 $var2";

}
?>
```

---

Check this  [complete example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete)

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the `FORM` tags so they have the correct attributes for `POST`. Try:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="text" value="gdf" name="text1" id="text1" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" id="display" name="display"><br /><br />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display text box and button on clicking submit button

```
<form>
<input type="submit"  value="OK" name="btn_name"/><br />
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['btn_name']))
           {
               echo "<input type=text name=txt_userinput />";
               echo "<input type=submit value=Area name='btn_calculate'/>";                  
           }
     ?>
</form>
```